# I want to get the array details which had a letter, but I can't get that

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want the word that contains a letter.

Output should be **:** `apple,banana,grape`

This is what I tried **:**

```
let fruits =["apple","banana","grape","cherry"];

let results =fruits.toString().match(/a/);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex to check if a string contains a character.

Using `filter` with `includes` you can keep the relevant words, and if you want to get a comma separated string, then you can use `join` with a comma:

```js
let fruits = ["apple", "banana", "grape", "cherry"];
let results = fruits.filter(s => s.includes('a'))

console.log(results);
console.log(results.join(','));
```